VSCode Autocomplete Issue - Problem with Path Aliases
I am experiencing an issue with the autocomplete feature in VSCode. I am developing a React app and not using TypeScript. After setting up path aliases, the auto-import functionality is not working correctly, and I'm looking for help.

 Environment

VSCode version : 1.92.1
OS version : Windows 10


I am using React + Vite + JavaScript.
Problem Situation

When writing the import statement directly, I can not see any path suggestions.
image 1

When importing specific components, multiple paths are suggested. Additionally, some of the paths using the alias '@' appear at the bottom.
image 2-1
image 2-2

When I select a recommended file path from the list, I import the file using destructuring. However, I have written the statement export default Input.
image 3


steps I have set up

vite.config.js configuration

export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react()],
  resolve: {
    alias: [
      { find: "@", replacement: "/src"}
    ]
  }
})


jsconfig.json configuration

{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "baseUrl": ".",
        "paths": {
            "@/*": [
                "src/*"
            ]
        }
    }
}


Vscode preference setting change - Import Module Specifier(non-relative)
vscode setting image

